# How to fetch array of objects using array of ids using core data?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I have an array of ids. I want to fetch core data entity for the items in the ids array. How can we implement that using `NSFetchRequest`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `NSPredicate`

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "itemId IN %@", itemIds)
```

Instead of `itemId` set your actual id property name. Now perform a fetch with this fetch request

Answer (score 0):

let hrData = self.cstProjectDetails as NSArray

Comment: The result of calling fetch is an array. You had an array to start with.

Then you did a very odd thing: you cast hrData to an NSArray. Well, an NSArray has no element type.

Comment: Swift doesn't have any information about what a logDetails even is. It just types it as an AnyObject.
If you want to extract its species property you will need to cast your //logDetails back down to whatever it really is, i.e. a CSTProjectDetails.
Alternatively, don't cast to an NSArray, since this erases your element type information. Cast down to a Swift array of CSTProjectDetails. Now Swift will have type information from the get-go.